# Puppet Could not find dependency

Tags: puppet

Is there a limitation of relationships?

We have several Puppet Modules which depend on each other (or at least depend on their packages).

I am asking this because now that I wanted to subscribe some services to restart if the dependency updates.

Problem:

```
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not find dependency Package[shibbolethsp] for Package[httpd] at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/development/modules/apache/manifests/instance.pp:39
```

Modules:

```
# Module someco-httpd, init.pp
package['httpd'] {
  ...
  require => Package['openssl','shibbolethsp'] # can find openssl but NOT shibbolethsp
}

# Module someco-openssl, init.pp
package['openssl'] {
  ...
}

# Module someco-shibbolethsp, init.pp
package['shibbolethsp'] {
  ...
}
```

The resource `Package[shibbolethsp]` IS present because if I remove the package and run puppet again I can see that it gets installed, but if I also want to configure Apache (which requires `Package[shibbolethsp]` to function properly) Puppet fails.

So the resource is present but Puppet can't resolve them properly I guess? The same relationship to `Package[openssl]` **works as expected** and Apache restarts if openssl updated to a new version ...

Is this a ordering/multithreading problem? One relationship works, the other doesn't ...

Comment: Are you sure that `shibbolethsp` is in your package repositories? Shibboleth isn't a typical package, so you would either need to download and install it by hand or add a repository containing it. Also, a quick Google doesn't turn up a package called `shibbolethsp`. Are you sure it isn't `shibboleth` or `shibboleth-sp`?

Comment: Hi @Jon ! Thank you very much for your reply! Yes, the ´shibbolethsp´ Package is in our repository, it also gets installed if I remove our "restart on dependency update - logic" ... the Package is our own built RPM in our own YUM Repo ... they exists, they get installed if configured without the "require => bla" relationship. the whole error occurs at catalog compilation time ...

Comment: In which case you probably just need to make the `shibbolethsp` package dependent on the installation of the `yum.repos.d` config. I'm guessing Puppet is just trying to do them in the wrong order and can't find the shib package.

Comment: One other thing is that your resource syntax is unusual. Rather than `package['name'] { }` the idiom is `package { 'name': }`. It probably doesn't matter, but I hadn't seen this usage before and had to check it in the docs!

Comment: What version of `puppet` do you have? My version 4.10.12 doesn't even compile the `package['httpd']` style declarations :-) It blows up with an error about string indexes.

Comment: @Jon yes you are right about the syntax, of course it's "package { 'name': }" I was just writing fast and forgot about the syntax here but you can be sure that I use the right syntax in my module :). We use Puppet 4.10 which gets shipped with Red Hat Satellite 6.3. your guess with the yum repo does not apply to this because ALL our packages come from the same yum repo (our own repo with our own built RPMs). For me with 6 months of full time Puppet development it seems that its 100% a puppet error or undocumented behaviour ...

Comment: @Jon The observed behavior would not be occurring if the package `shibbolethsp` was not in an available package repository. This is a purely puppet parser issue.

Comment: @Pali Do you mind sharing the contents of the `classes.txt` inside the `cachedir` https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/dirs_vardir.html#location-of-the-vardir-directory? This would be for a node that applies the catalog you are describing above.

Comment: the current content is:
settings
puppetdev-d00
module_global_settings
java

Comment: @Jon see my own answer for the solution

Answer (score 2):

The problems are cross module dependencies. Resources in other modules live in a different namespace than the current module. So if you depend on a resource from another module you have to use the full path, e.g. `Other_module::Other_class_or_defined_type['bla']` or use `require Other_module` in your `init.pp`s to ensure the right ordering!

**NOTE**: in the `site.pp` you have to define the resources in their right order!

Answer (score -3):

> The resource `Package[shibbolethsp]` IS present because if I remove
>   the package and run puppet again I can see that it gets installed,

Your observation does not support the conclusion.

For one thing, it is entirely possible for a package to be installed as a result of a Puppet run even though no `Package` resource for it is included in the catalog.  This happens all the time, in fact.  It is driven by dependencies expressed in the packages themselves, where *the package manager* (Yum, apt, *etc*.) identifies the dependencies of a package it is installing and arranges to install those, too.  Puppet has no insight into that.

For another thing, it is entirely possible for `Package[shibbolethsp]` to be declared in the catalog for one node, but not in the catalog for a different node.  Naturally, if you uninstall `shibbolethsp` from a node of the first kind, then Puppet will reinstall it on its next run.  In no way does that demonstrate that the package is declared in a different node's catalog.

> but
>   if I also want to configure Apache (which requires
>   `Package[shibbolethsp]` to function properly) Puppet fails.

Which tells me that no, you are *not* declaring `Package[shibbolethsp]` in the affected node's catalog, your protestations to the contrary notwithstanding.

> So the resource is present but Puppet can't resolve them properly I
>   guess? The same relationship to `Package[openssl]` **works as
>   expected** and Apache restarts if openssl updated to a new version ...

I see no reason to think that either relationship fails to work as *should be* expected, but I suspect you have incorrect expectations.

In the first place, Puppet resource and class relationships are about *order of application* dependencies.  E.g. `File[/etc/foo.conf]` needs to be ensured up to date before `Service[foo]` is managed *because otherwise the foo service may not be managed into the correct state*.  This is largely, albeit not wholly, separate from functional dependency between managed components.

In the second place, I think you are assuming that your `require` relationships between `Package` resources will cause the required `Package`s to be declared in the event that their requirer is declared.  This is completely incorrect.  Again, Puppet resource relationships are about order of application.  Puppet cannot autodeclare `require`d resources because it relies on you to tell it what properties they have, and also because that would produce a serious risk of duplicate declarations.

Overall, it is rarely useful to declare relationships between `Package` resources at the Puppet level, as functional dependencies between packages are best handled at the package / package manager level, and there typically aren't any other *bona fide* order-of-application dependencies between pairs of packages.

---

If you want shibboleth to be on machines that get Apache, then you need to ensure that the appropriate class is declared.  You may also have some order of application considerations at a different level than the packages -- for example, you may need to ensure that Shibboleth is installed before you manage the Apache *service*, and perhaps also you want to restart the service if ever the shibboleth package or configuration is updated.  You would arrange for that best at the class level, not in individual resource declarations.

For example the `httpd` module class of module someco-httpd might include something like this:

```
# Nodes to which this class is applied require class ::shibbolethsp to be applied first
require '::shibbolethsp'
```

Unlike resources' `require` metaparameter, that does cause the named class, `shibbolethsp` to be evaluated (presumably producing a declaration of `Package[shibbolethsp]`, among others), and it also creates an order-of-application relationship so that the `shibbolethsp` class is applied first.  And again, the order-of-application is not for the purpose of a package / package relationship, but rather for a more general class / class relationship that covers the dependency of the `httpd` *service* on having shibboleth installed and configured.

Comment: 1. we build the RPM packages by ourselfe (all of them). they there is no dependency in any RPM which would install shibbolethsp, only Puppet can install it
2. your whole answer is useless for me because you are expressing the official documentation to me ... the whole problem seems about ordering at compile time or what else ...
3. the whole thing works for OpenSSL but not for Shibboleth SP so I have no idea what you want to tell me :/

Comment: @Pali, I am summarizing relevant portions of the official documentation to you because the documentation is *accurate* in these regards.  I'm sorry if that wasn't what you wanted to hear, but it's the truth.  If you think you are observing different behavior then it would behoove you to reduce it to a [mcve] that you can present in your question.  Chances are good that you'll solve the problem yourself that way, but if you don't, we should be able to do.

Comment: I am trying to get a minimal, reproducable example but what if the problem only occurs on big puppet configurations? all I can tell you is that I actually observe strange, undocumented behaviour ... I will try again to get a working "bad" example next week and let you hear from it ...